# how do I activate interactive python help in visual studio like in spyder

Tags: python, visual-studio, spyder

I'd like to get automatic context help in VS2017, similar to what is displayed inside spyder, when I click on an object that has help for it in the python manuals.
I's this possible? 
[interactive window example from spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGaCs.jpg)
I'm looking for a window that is part of the IDE, and not a pop-up that is shown when "." is pressed

Answer (score 1):

You can hover your mouse over an object or method to see a tooltip of it.

You can also use the dot operator(<kbd>.</kbd>) to bring up intellisense for a list of properties and methods. If intellisense doesn't immediately pop up after pressing the <kbd>.</kbd> key, you can also press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to force it open.

Lastly, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> with your cursor in an object, method or variable to go to its definition.

Comment: what id really want is be able to add a window, say, at the bottom, that shows the snippet that is shown when pressing ',', or ctrl-space. I hate the fact that the help snippet disappears after afew seconds.

Comment: There's nothing I know of like that in Visual Studio. The Intellisense menu is context based and available items become more focused the more you type.